# Data in table not affected by DELETE query in MySQL database using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table `test` in which I want to delete the record. I am using the delete query, but no effect. I tried running it in SQL tab in `phpmyadmin` and it works there. But, in `php` code, it is not working. Here is the `HTML` code

```
<form action="home.php" method="post">
  <button class="button button3" type="button" onclick="return 
  toggleMe('del_tst')">Delete Test</button><br>
  <div id="del_tst" style="display:none">
  <input type="date" class="textstyle" name="tst_date" method="post" 
  placeholder="Enter test date" />
  <button type="submit" class="subbutton button1" value="Delete" 
  method="post" 
  name="del_tst">Delete</button><br/>
  </div>
</form>
```

and here is php code

```
if(isset($_POST['del_tst'])){
 $tst_date= date('d-m-Y', strtotime( $_POST['tst_date'] ));

try{
    $stmt_tst=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `test` WHERE `date`=:tst_date"); 

    $stmt_tst->bindparam(":tst_date",$tst_date);
    $result=$stmt->execute();
    if($result===TRUE)
    {
        if(($stmt->rowCount())>0)
        {
            echo "<font color='white'> <i>record Deleted successfully!</i></font>";
        }
        else{
          echo "<font color='white'> <i>No such record exists!</i></font>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Something Went Wrong!";
    }

    return true; 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
 echo $e->getMessage(); 
 return false;
}
}
```

I am trying to delete the record using `date` in `WHERE` condition, but not working. 
Here's the screenshot of database
[image: database]

Please be with me to solve this problem.

Comment: your form has an invalid syntax. I.e. the fields don't have a method property. Check the html and see if the form is posting regularly to the php page.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I tried with removing method attribute from input fields, but it has no effect. It is still not working.

Answer (score 1):

This part is incorrect:

```
$stmt_tst=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `test` WHERE `date`='.$tst_date.'");
$stmt_tst->bindparam(":tst_date",$tst_date);
$result=$stmt->execute();
```

you should change it so:

```
$stmt_tst=$conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `test` WHERE `date`=:tst_date");
$stmt_tst->bindparam(":tst_date",$tst_date);
$result=$stmt->execute();
```

See more in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Also, if `date` is a MySQL `DATE` column, you should use ISO8601 dates (year first):

```
$tst_date= date('Y-m-d', strtotime( $_POST['tst_date'] ));
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with it also, but unfortunately not worked.

Comment: Why? You should always try to use the correct data type.

Comment: I tried running the query with SQL tab, it is running there. I think data type is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I'd try to change your query to:

```
("DELETE FROM `test` WHERE `date`= '".$tst_date."'");
```

Note the extra double quotes around $tst_date

Comment: no, it is correct. OP is using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

you should fix your form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="home.php" method="post">
  <input type="date" class="textstyle" name="tst_date" placeholder="Enter test date" />
  <input type="submit" class="subbutton button1" value="Delete" name="del_tst">Delete</button><br/>
  </form>
```

Try with this light version that should post the values to the PHP page. Then use your browser inspection tool to see if it is properly posting

N.B. this works together with @bart's answer

Comment: as your suggestion, I tried to change the code from `input` type to `button` tag. But   no effect.

Comment: Is the form posting to the php page?

Comment: yes, I have tried to echo the `$tst_date` variable and it gives date as `08-06-2018`

Comment: This date will never be stored in your dB if the field is a date type. The format is yyyy-mm-dd and not dd-mm-yyyy as you have now

Comment: @ Lelio Faieta the `date` field is simple `varchar` type, not `date`